# Getting error in react 16 while setting a state from JSON object data.results

Tags: reactjs

Getting error in react 16 while setting a state from JSON object data.results

Here's the error

```
x ←→ 1 of 2 errors on the page
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {gender, name, location, email, login, dob, registered, phone, cell, id, picture, nat}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at App.js:47)
    in App (at index.js:7)
```

Here's the code

```
componentDidMount()
{
  fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50').then(results=>{
    return results.json().then(data => {
      this.setState(
      {
        pictures : data.results
      });
      console.log(data.results);
    });


  });
```

Comment: it looks more like a problem in your `render()` method to me, can you share the whole app code out?

Comment: Also, It is not clear to me if the function `.json()` returns a `promise` hence not 'thenable'

Comment: @brandNew It does. But it makes no sense to return `results.json().then(…)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Objects are not valid as a React child
```

This error means, you return plain js object as `child`, which is not allowed. You have to map it, wrap with some markup. Unfortunately, you did not provide full source code for that component.

I think the actual error is somewhere inside your `render()` method.